# Post to friend's feed not working with phonegap facebook plugin

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I install the [Phonegap Facebook Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) in Cordova 3.3.1.

Then I'm testing examples from this package. I copied index page from `examples/simple` folder. I trind login, worked. I tried logout, worked. I triend friendlist, wallpost , all waorked. **But post to friend's wall failed.**

I took necessary permissions like `publish_actions`. Still it didn't post anything to friend's wall. I can assure you that friend's wall is open for posts.

Here are some codes to initialize, and post to friends wall

```
FB.init({
    appId: "MY_APP_ID",
    nativeInterface: CDV.FB, 
    useCachedDialogs: false, 
    logging: true,
    cookie: true,
    frictionlessRequests: true,
    oauth: true
});

FB.login(
    function(response) {
        if (response.session) {
            alert('logged in');
        }
        else {
            alert('not logged in');
        }
    },{ scope: "email,publish_actions" }
);

function publishStoryFriend() {
    //randNum = Math.floor ( Math.random() * friendIDs.length ); 

    //var friendID = friendIDs[randNum];
    var friendID = "KNOWN_ID_OF_A_FRIEND";
    if (friendID == undefined) {
        alert('please click the me button to get a list of friends first');
    }
    else {
        console.log("friend id: " + friendID );
        console.log('Opening a dialog for friendID: '+ friendID);
        var params = {
            method: 'feed',
            to: friendID.toString(),
            name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
            link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
            picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
            caption: 'Reference Documentation',
            description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
        };
        FB.ui(params, function(obj) { console.log(obj); alert(obj);});
    }
}
```

Now **no error, but no post on friends wall either**. I initialized the `friendID` with a known ID of a friend. No error, it shows the post page from facebook perfectly. but after pressing share nothing posts on friend's wall, also gives me a alert "OK".

What I'm missing? What's wrong? Do I need any extra permission! or do I need to make change in my facebook app settings??

Comment: Mannn, I have this problem also and I can't figure out why it happens!!!

Comment: So far I knew that Facebook revoked that functionality in recent sdks. And I gave up. @DorR